# flowplayer video on ipad/ipod touch not working in drupal7 using ipad plugin - byte range headers problem

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, drupal, flowplayer

I've successfully integrated Flowplayer into my Drupal installation using the [video](http://drupal.org/project/video) and [flowplayer](http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer). I upgraded flowplayer files to the latest release 3.2.7 and all works ok, but not on iPad - iPod Touch.

I loaded the js for the iPad [plugin](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/ipad.html) in the Flowplayer module like this:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'flowplayer') . '/flowplayer/example/flowplayer.ipad-3.2.2.js');
```

and I see that it is loaded fine.

then in Flowplayer js I had this line

```
$(selector + ':not(.flowplayer-processed)').addClass('flowplayer-processed').flowplayer(settings.basePath + settings.flowplayerSwf, config);
```

I changed this in this way:

```
//I added the first line because in  the example it worked that way
$(selector + ':not(.flowplayer-processed)').attr('url', config.clip.url);
$(selector + ':not(.flowplayer-processed)').addClass('flowplayer-processed').flowplayer(settings.basePath + settings.flowplayerSwf, config);
//then i add ipad support (the selctor is hardcoded to maike things work)
$f('flowplayer-video').ipad();
```

In this way, on my iPod touch (I think it's the same on iPad) I see the player but the video doesn't start (there is some kind of blocked overlay).

You can look at the site [here](http://85.94.221.106/drupal/?q=node/5#)

EDIT - now i got it working thanks to teddy suggestion. now i'll try to find out how to setup my script so that it returns `byte-range` headers.

If anyone knows how to do this, please post here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server that serves the actual MP4 video to the iPad must support the HTTP header called `byte-range`.

I would try using an alternate video source from another server, as a proof-of-concept to see if this is the cause of the problem.

Here is an MP4 video served with the `byte-range` header: http://mediaelementjs.com/media/echo-hereweare.mp4

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't work anyway, i'v edited my post with the url to your video. The video must be hosted on my server, do you mean i have to set something in my server?

Comment: You would only need to change your sever if the test video I referenced "worked" when served from mediaelementjs.com servers.  If it still doesn't work, something else is wrong.

Comment: no, i didn't try to serve it from mediaelements, i downloaded and uploaded it: i'll trey to do as you say.

Comment: That's it, if i use the video streamed from mediaelements.js, it works!How should i set those headers?Can i do it with php `Headers()` function?

Comment: Yes, I think you can.  Please post your solution to the original question if you get it working.